# Docker with Jupyter Notebook and Spark

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use docker to run Jupyter Notebook with spark , on PowerShell I am using the following command:

```
docker run --rm -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8888:8888 -e PYTHONHASHSEED=0 jupyter/all-spark-notebook
```

When I run that I get the following error:

```
Container must be run with group "root" to update passwd file
```

Any Ideas about how to fix it/ update group root password?